# Cube portfolio pop up image went wrong

Tags: media

I am using Cube Portfolio to display portfolios.

The "View Larger" button link shows the correct link.

[image]

But when I click on the button,

the pop up image went wrong.

[image]

How do I find out the problem?

I look into the code, there is a weird link.

[image]

The portfolio section was created in Views. Drupal version is 7.

Comment: As per your first image, the file path what it is showing is `sites/default/files/works-img36.jpg`, Did you check in this folder, whether that file .jpg file is acually available?

Comment: The path is correct. There is an image in it.

Comment: Could you provide the link of module, Cube Portfolio, If I will get a time I will test at my end, to figure out the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image path changes to absoulute path.